# Vue.js Передать набор данных в компонент

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста в таком вопросе с Vue.
Есть посты с категориями. Есть динамическое меню, при клике на которое, выводились бы посты с этой категории с пагинатором. Каким образом при клике на пункт меню передать набор данных выбранной категории в post-component, чтобы он отобразил его.

v-on:click="getcat(cat_id)" в меню получает данные, но как отобразить его в post-component ?

С vue только разбираться начал, вполне возможно пошёл по абсолютно неправильному пути.

welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @if($menu)
        @foreach ($menu as $mm)
            @include('mitems', ['item'=>$mm])
        @endforeach                             
    @endif
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
    <post-component></post-component>
</div>
```

post-component.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
   <div v-for="post in laravelData.data">
            //информация
    </div>  
      <pagination :limit="5" :data="laravelData" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
    </div>
    </template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                laravelData: {},
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getResults();
        },
        methods: { 
            getResults(page) {
                if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
                    page = 1;
                }
                this.$http.get('/post?page=' + page)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    }).then(data => {
                        this.laravelData = data;
                    });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',    
    methods : {
           getcat: function (key) {
           this.$http.get('/post?cat_id=' + key)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    }).then(data => {
                        this.laravelData = data;
                    });
        },
    }    
});
```

Comment: В официальной документации vue.js все подробно и даже на русском расписано. Советую почитать бегло чтобы в голове хотя бы отложилась мысль о что где-то я уже это видел.

Comment: [Ссылка вот](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: Из вашего примера абсолютно непонятно как выглядит меню и в каком оно компоненте. В любом случае vue это чисто spa, и серверный рендеринг ни к чему хорошему не приведет. А данные в компоненту передавать через props или сразу vuex.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev уточните, пожалуйста, почему vue чисто spa и где Вы увидели ssr?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько – хм, `welcome.blade.php`, `@if`, не ssr? А взял что я пробовал его запускать на большом ssr проекте, и это не закончилось успехом. Но если у вас есть примеры реализации, то буду рад посмотреть

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev отчасти Вы правы, это может быть ssr потому что это blade.php в который могут вставляться данные из php которые на клиенте будут уже в готовом виде, но в данном случае в blade есть vue компоненты, которые не обрабатываются на сервере чтобы из них получился готовый хтмл(чтобы когда нажимаешь `Ctrl + U` было видно), это уже будет работа браузера который получает js и по нему строит хтмл. А так ssr в vue очень хорошо развит, есть [vue-server-renderer](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/) и есть очень удобный [nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js)(типа как next в react).

Comment: Обычно когда делают ssr, то отделяются от laravel blade и вообще не используют его, а laravel чисто как api. Надеюсь, прояснил картину, буду рад если исправите меня в чем-то.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, вот вы и пришли к моему ответу. Vue чисто spa. И использовать его вместе с серверным рендерингом практически нельзя. Я не говорю о рендеринге вьюхи на сервере, а о работе вместе с отрендереным html

Comment: Видимо я ошибся в сообщении, ssr не касается blade вообще, то есть когда даешь html с контентом сгенерированным в blade, то это не ssr. ssr это когда выполняешь js код чтобы не выполнять его на клиенте. Вы писали `В любом случае vue это чисто spa, и серверный рендеринг ни к чему хорошему не приведет.` Это же явно не правда? Я привел вполне хорошие инструменты. Наверное Вы имели в виду что spa вместе с blade плохая идея? Это да, лучше делать отделенное приложение (через Vue cli, например).

Comment: [вот](https://github.com/yyx990803/laravel-vue-cli-3) хороший пример как сделать vue cli + laravel и как через laravel можно открывать production build, очень хороший пример.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что Вы используете blade, а не чисто vue компоненты во фронтенде, это не так удобно как по мне и ограничивает, у Вас вроде даже live reload не будет работать, надо самоуму страницу перезагружать. Страница `welcome.blade.php` могла бы быть компонентом vue, та и вообще все страницы компонентами vue которые работали бы через vue router, а laravel был бы хорош чисто как API с которого можно получить данные и vue с ними работал. Если бы у Вас был laravel как API, то вы могли бы в компоненте Welcome.vue(страница вместо welcome.blade.php) получить меню с бэкенда laravel и красиво вывести его через v-for, в котором бы выводили компоненты меню, примерно так:

```
<menu-item
  v-for="(item, index) in mitems"
  key="'menu-' + index"
  @menuClick="showCategory"
/>
```

Я указал [пользовательское событие](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#ad) `menuClick` которое создается внутри самого компонента через $emit и идет наружу где родитель-компонент(в шаблоне которого помещен `menu-item`, то есть это Welcome.vue) его ловит через `@menuClick`, в это событие можно передать данные о категории. showCategory это обработчик события, который содержится в methods компонента Welcome.vue, который может получить категории и делать с ними что надо.

Про компоненты можно узнать лучше [здесь](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Надеюсь я прояснил Вашу картину и Вы поняли в каком направлении двигаться.

**update**: код примера почему-то в начале не высветился))